# Logout error occurs in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to logout but I get an error

> ReflectionException (-1) Class App\Http\Controllers\LoginController
>   does not exist

I added logout method in the `LoginController` but it doesn't work

LoginController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller {

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    public function logout(Request $request) {
        $this->guard()->logout();

        $request->session()->invalidate();

        return redirect('/index');
    }

}
```

Blade.php file

```
<ul id="dropdown1" class="dropdown-content">
    <li><a href="#!">Parametres</a></li>
    <li><a href="/logout">Deonnexion</a></li> 
</ul>
```

Routes

```
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/logout', 'LoginController@logout');
```

Comment: `Auth::->guard()->logout();` -> `Auth::guard()->logout();` ?

Comment: even with $this->guard()->logout(); it doesn't work

Comment: What the error says is that, it cannot find the controller class (maybe filename, class name incorrect, or the cache from composer). Make sure your `LoginController.php` file is in `app\Http\Controllers\` directory. Then run `composer dump-autoload` and try again. Does it work?

Comment: @spicydog  I've tried  this route : Route::get('logout', 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout');
but still get the same error :( and I ran composer too as you told me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It worked finally after adding

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
```

to the LoginController.php file

Comment: please marked it as solved if you found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check namespace ?
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers

Comment: namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

they already exist